# how to make content disappear when an event occurs

Tags: jquery

i am using the following script for side-panel collapse:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
$('.collaps').addClass('collaps_on');
  var showFlag=1
  $('.collaps').click(function() {
   if(showFlag==1){
     $('#adminmenuback').animate({width:"5%"});
     $('.three-fourth').animate({width:"93%"});
       $('ul.admin-menu li a').addClass("newgradient");

     if($('.collaps').hasClass("collaps_on") ){
        $('.collaps').addClass("collaps_off");
        $('.collaps').removeClass("collaps_on");

     }
     else{
     $('.collaps').addClass("collaps_on");
     $('.collaps').removeClass("collaps_off");

     }

      showFlag=0;
   }else{
   $('ul.admin-menu li a').removeClass("newgradient");
     $('#adminmenuback').animate({width:"17%"});
     $('.three-fourth').animate({width:"81%"});

             if($('.collaps').hasClass("collaps_off") ){
        $('.collaps').addClass("collaps_on");
        $('.collaps').removeClass("collaps_off");

     }
     else{
     $('.collaps').addClass("collaps_off");
     $('.collaps').removeClass("collaps_on");

     }

    showFlag=1;
   }     
  });
});

</script>
```

the html of side-panel is like this:

```
<section class="one-fourth" id="adminmenuback">
    <ul class="admin-menu">

    <li><a href="#" class="collaps">button</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> <span class="home"></span>Dashboard </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> <span class="home"></span>Dashboard </a></li>

    </ul>


</section>
```

its working fine, the only thing is that i want the name of links ( for eg. where it is written "dashbord" ) to disappear when i collapse the width of side-panel (#adminmenuback) to 5%. 
here is the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/kF38Q/
thanks in advance

Comment: can you please create fiddle for this.?

Comment: here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kF38Q/

Answer (score 0):

give the items that you want to let disappear an id and then just use `$('#idOfObject').fadeOut()` to hide it.

if you want them to reappear use `$('#idOfObject').fadeIn()`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I didn't understand it correctly. But you can add a new function when the animation is done to remove the text of the links:

```
$('#adminmenuback').animate({width:"5%"}, function(){
          $('#adminmenuback a').text('');
        }
```

If you add `overflow: hidden` to #adminmenuback then the text will disappear based on the width.

Comment: is there a way where .text('') can be reversed? actually i added .text('') like this: $(document).ready(function(){
$('.collaps').addClass('collaps_on');
  var showFlag=1
  $('.collaps').click(function() {
   if(showFlag==1){
     $('#adminmenuback').animate({width:"5%"});
     $('.three-fourth').animate({width:"93%"});
       $('ul.admin-menu li a').addClass("newgradient");
       $('ul.admin-menu li a').not('.collaps').text(' ');